# If $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $\det(A) = 4$, then compute $\det(((-9A)^4)^T)$.

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Given a $3\times3$ matrix $A$
>   $$A= \begin{bmatrix}
> a & b & c \\
> d & e & f \\
> g & h & i \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   and $\det(A)=4$
>
> Calculate $\det(((-9)\cdot A)^4)^T$.

Comment: **Hint:** Ignore the entries of $A$ completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints:** If $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $k \in \mathbb N$, then:

- $\det(M^T) = \det M$
- $\det(M^k) = (\det M)^k$
- $\det(kM) = k^n\det M$

Comment: Note that the second and third properties are a both consequence of $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the properties of determinant:

1. $\det A=\det A^T$
2. If $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix then $\det cA=c^n\det A$
3. $\det (AB)=(\det A)(\det B)$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The answer is $4^4\cdot{(-9)}^{12}$.

Answer (score 0):

First recall

1. $det(A^p) = det(A)^p$
2. $det(A^T) = det(A)^T$
3. $det(kA) = k^ndet(A)$ where n is the size of the matrix (3 in your case: 3 rows and 3 columns).

$$\begin{split}
det((((−9)⋅A)^4)^T &= det(((−9)⋅A)^4$  \text{ by property 2}\\
 &= [det((−9)⋅A)]^4$   \text{ by property 1} \\
 &= [(−9)^3⋅det(A)]^4$   \text{ by property 3} \\
 &= [(−9)^3⋅4]^4$   \text{ by your note det(A) =4}.
 \end{split}
$$